# Customize node add page / Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I need to customise the theme for the node add page in Drupal 8. I know how to customise the node page but not the add/edit pages.

**EDIT** (since this is closed and cannot be answered, but there is in fact a good answer)

Contrib solution (for Drupal 7 and modern Drupal) that makes it easy, providing a separate menu to power a replacement "Add content" page:

https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_add_content

(This can stay closed as there are open ones with the same question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228050/reorder-content-types-in-node-add/316676 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the `/node/add` page or the `/node/add/{type}` page?

The former uses the theme hook `node_add_list` (see https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/blob/8.8.x/core/modules/node/src/Controller/NodeController.php)

The latter page is just a form with the ID `node_form`, so it can be altered with `hook_form_node_form_alter` - see this question for how to alter a form to send it to a custom template: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146434/send-a-form-to-twig-template

PS: I recommend https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ for Drupal-related questions.